Export only some visible parts of an object as SVG
I am making a striped tunnel like this:

The result looks like this which is very satisfying:

However I want to export only the black rings, and as a SVG from Blender.
I have converted the object as a Grease Pencil, then exported as a SVG but the result makes the black and white rings the same color, which is too confusing:

So I decided to delete the faces corresponding to the white rings in Blender, and convert to Grease Pencil then export only the black rings as a SVG.
However the resulting SVG element is very difficult to work with, because it exported the whole shape as vector elements placed on top of one another:

Removing the hidden part of the tunnel is extremely tedious in Illustrator, because some shapes are half-way between visible part and hidden part and therefore need to be edited one by one.

I tried exporting the black rings as one vector file and the white rings as another one to do a Pathfinder effect in Illustrator but that also didn't work as it removed parts of the black rings as well:

How can I export only the black rings in the camera's point of view of Image 2, without the invisible parts that are hidden ?

